# Passing parameters to the new controller action in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to call a controller's new action to create a new object using an existing one to set defaults. So far, what I've done to to try this:

`link_to 'New' new_item_path(t)`

In a Wice Grid table where `t` is an instance of `item`.

The route that gets generated is `/item/new.10` where the 10 is the `:id` of the item that I'd like to use as a default. I can get at it through `request.referrer`, but I'm wondering if there is a better/cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're setting defaults on a new object, you should consider setting those defaults at the database level within a migration.  To keep your system RESTful, you should keep the 'new' action url independent of the object you're grabbing defaults from i.e. just /item/new.

If you want to set defaults from the existing object without applying at the database level, you should consider creating an instance variable in your controller action, and using that in your view to set the default values in your form elements.  Another option would be to edit the object in a before_create callback within your model and set the fields there.  Changing your route to accommodate this idea would be bad design IMO.

Passing the id to your controller as a param:

```
link_to "New Item Path", new_item_path(:default_item_id => item.id)
```

in your controller

```
   @default_item = Item.find(params[:default_item_id])
```

Comment: So, I guess the question is how to get the id of the object that I want to use as the default passed to the new action?

Comment: Is it the same object every time or unique to the specific resource? You can always use link_to link_to 'New' new_item_path(:default => id), which will pass the id of the object in the params hash, so item/new?default=id, which is RESTful, preferred and you can grab the default object in your controller action by calling @object = Object.find(params[:default])

Comment: It is unique. The new object will be a derivative of an existing object (it will inherit some values from it) but it will also have fields that get new values. There is not one canonical object that they all derive from.

Comment: I'd use the method added in my comment above. You don't want to modify the new action URL, pass the id as a param in your link_to helper

Answer (score 1):

`request.referrer`? You should be able to get at the id in you controller through `params`

Not sure if it's an issue but there should be a comma in between 'New' and the path specification

```
link_to 'New', new_item_path(t)
```

then in the controller you can setup strong params if you want to be thorough

```
ItemsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    # new action
  end

  def create
    item = Item.new(item_params)

    if item.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Successfully created your item.'
      redirect_to item #if there's an item#show page
    else
      flash[:alert] = 'Error: item not created.'
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit(:attribute_1, :attribute_2, ...)
  end
end
```

Hope this helps